# Press Button and drag it over the screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make an application where the user can place the elements.

Here is my problem:
I want to press a button (mousedown) and while I move mouse the button should move with my mousemovements.

How can I program this in `c# WPF` ?
Do I have to use the "margin" property?

Regards

Comment: Use the MouseMove event handler of the WPF window. When it fires, if button is pressed, get the position coordinates of the mouse. With that coordinates, you just play with margin values to place the button on the new position.

Comment: Yes... it works. Thank you. My error was to use the MouseMove event handler of the button.

Comment: Now i have new problem. When i press the button and stay pressed, the MouseMove event did not appear when i move the mouse. After i release the Button the MouseMove event works again. But i want to press the button and move as long as i press.

Comment: Added an explained example to drag and drop the button within a WPF window using right mouse click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace dragdropButton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        /// Tells whether the button is being pressed or not
        private bool buttonPressed;

        #region Imports method to determinate the mouse position
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct Win32Point
        {
            public Int32 X;
            public Int32 Y;
        };

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtains the mouse current position
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Position coordinates</returns>
        public static Point GetMousePosition()
        {
            Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
            GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
            return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
        }
        #endregion

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the distance between two 2-dimensional points A and B
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pt">Point A</param>
        /// <param name="x">X coordinate of B</param>
        /// <param name="y">Y coordinate of B</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private double EuclideanDist(Point pt, double x, double y)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(pt.X - x, 2) + Math.Pow(pt.Y - y, 2));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Maps the left margin to the current mouse position
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pt">Mouse current position</param>
        /// <returns>Left margin</returns>
        private double GetLeftMargin(Point pt)
        {
            double x = 0;
            double y = pt.Y;
            return EuclideanDist(pt, x, y);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Maps the top margin to the current mouse position
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pt">Mouse current position</param>
        /// <returns>Top margin</returns>
        private double GetTopMargin(Point pt)
        {
            double x = pt.X;
            double y = 0;
            return EuclideanDist(pt, x, y);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires when mouse moves within this WPF window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Window_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // if button is being pressed
            if (buttonPressed)
            {
                // get the mouse current position
                Point pt = GetMousePosition();

                // set the new button position
                this.button.Margin = new Thickness(GetLeftMargin(pt), GetTopMargin(pt), 0, 0);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires whe button is pressed by mouse right click
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            buttonPressed = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Firew when the button is released by mouse right click
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            buttonPressed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="dragdropButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dragdropButton"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="418" Width="779"
        PreviewMouseMove="Window_PreviewMouseMove">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" MouseUp="button_MouseUp" MouseDown="button_MouseDown" Height="40"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```